# How to Enable protected content in a webview?

Tags: android, webview

In chrome browser, there is an option to **play protected content**. How do I enable the same in **webview** in **android**?

I have tried a method called `allowContentAccess()` but that does not work.

Please help

Answer (score 7):

To allow a webview to play a DRM content you have to grant RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID permission to the webview.

You can do it by override of WebChromeClient#onPermissionRequest

As a sample:

```
    @Override
    public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
        String[] resources = request.getResources();
        for (int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
            if (PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID.equals(resources[i])) {
                request.grant(resources);
                return;
            }
        }

        super.onPermissionRequest(request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`setAllowContentAccess()` (I couldn't find the `allowContentAccess()` you mentioned) is [used for accessing local content files on the device](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setAllowContentAccess(boolean)), not for protected content.

Protected content viewing enabling is usually controlled by the user, not the developer unfortunately. For example, for the default browser Chrome according to [this help article](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/4410268?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1):

> Chrome will play protected content by default.
>
> If you don't want Chrome to play protected content by default, you can
>   change your settings:
>
> 1. On your Android phone or tablet, open the Chrome app Chrome.
> 2. To the right of the address bar, tap More More and then Settings.
> 3. Tap Site settings and then Media and then Protected Content.
> 4. Select Ask first.

Since accessing protected content requires the site viewing information about your device, I expect this isn't available through a `WebView`.

There is a [full built-in framework available](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary) (since API level 11) for managing DRM content that should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Following Viacheslav's answer which works perfectly, here's the same snippet in Kotlin, to allow the WebView to play DRM content:

```
        override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest?) {
            request?.let { request ->
                if (request.resources.contains(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID)) {
                    request.grant(request.resources)
                    return
                }
            }

            super.onPermissionRequest(request)
        }
```