# How to play widevine drm content in react native webview or exoplayer?

Tags: react-native, webview, exoplayer, widevine

I need to integrate a website to the WebView of my react native application. Website delivers DRM protected videos, to maintain the authentication flow of the website I am using webview as I don't want any legal complications later. How can I play widevine DRM videos in webview ? I have one solution in mind i.e. after authentication take the video source somehow and play it with exoplayer, but cannot figure out how to do so. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: On Android devices the webview may play DRM protected videos after enabling some flags on native side. But on iOS can be very difficult to enable it, due the Apple restrictions.

Comment: Thanks, Do you know what flags needs to be enabled on native side for this to work on android devices?

Comment: This question maybe help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53143363/how-to-enable-protected-content-in-a-webview